# Progress bar for consolidation loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this consolidation macro which opens, copies and pastes data from one sheet of several workbooks onto a master sheet where such data as well as workbooks maybe in the thousands. Overall this process will take anywhere from 30mins to an hour and I thought a progress bar would help.

I got the code i used for the consolidation part here at stackoverflow. It was somebody with a similar issue, however, the progress bar code i got somewhere else. I had to jury-rig the code of sorts to fit it for my needs.. The examples online uses a for next loop code for the progress bar which mine doesn't.

i tried running my code but the progress bar doesn't update.. T_T

can somebody help me with what's wrong with my code?
Any help on this is very much appreciated.. thanks..

```
Sub OpeningFiles()


Dim SelectedFiles As FileDialog
Dim NumFiles As Long, FileIndex As Long
Dim TargetBook As Workbook
Dim sName, sName2, sName3 As Range
Dim pctCompl As Single

Set sName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("j1")


Set SelectedFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With SelectedFiles
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Title = "Pick the files you'd like to consolidate:"
.ButtonName = ""
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add ".xlsx files", "*.xlsx"
.Show
End With


If SelectedFiles.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub


NumFiles = SelectedFiles.SelectedItems.Count
For FileIndex = 1 To NumFiles

Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFiles.SelectedItems(FileIndex), ReadOnly:=True)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Activate

Sheets(sName).Activate
On Error GoTo 0
Range("d11:j11").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("b2").Select
 Do
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


ThisWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
TargetBook.Close SaveChanges:=False




Next FileIndex

progress pctCompl

MsgBox ("Consolidation complete!")

End Sub
Sub progress(pctCompl As Single)

UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2

DoEvents

End Sub

Sub ShowProgress()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Addendum:

This code

```
Sheets(sName).activate
```

selects the sheetname of the opened file wherein it is always a number from 1-30. Right now, I have to indicate that number one at a time. Is there a way to do it like 3 or 7 times? like a loop? e.g 1-7 or 25-27.. It is always ascending so i thought a code like the one below will work? Thoughts?

```
For sName = sNameStart To sNameEnd Step 1

Sheets(sName).Activate


On Error GoTo 0
Range("d11:j11").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("b2").Select
 Do
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveWorkbook.Activate

Next sName
```

where sName is the sheet name, sNameStart is the start sheet and sNameEnd is the end sheet.
However, i get this error when I start this code.. Help?

Comment: `UserForm1.show vbModeless`

Comment: You need to update the value of `pctCompl` and call `progress` somewhere in your `For` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your call to `progress pctCompl` inside your loop.

The code you posted doesn't call `progress pctCompl` until after `Next FileIndex`

```
ThisWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
TargetBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next FileIndex

progress pctCompl

MsgBox ("Consolidation complete!")
```

Replace it with this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
TargetBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
'insert your command here
progress pctCompl

Next FileIndex


MsgBox ("Consolidation complete!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more precise than progress bar try putting:
`Application.StatusBar = "File " & FileIndex & " of " & NumFiles`
somewhere within `For..Next` loop, I like this because it is more verbose than just progress bar.
And remember to put
`Application.StatusBar = False`
After your loop to restore standard status bar.

Comment: perfect! yeah this was so much better!

Comment: i was able to use some insights on your suggestion as well as based on Mark Fitzgerald's answer to come up with the progress bar.. thanks much guys!